# Issue with PrintToPrinter method

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using the PrintToPrinter method to print my crystal report,I have written it in my code
like this:

```
PetroDLL.Reports.rptBrokerageBillReportSeller2 rpt =
         new PetroDLL.Reports.rptBrokerageBillReportSeller2();
rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

but this prints 2 copies,while I just want 1.Kindly pardon my ignorance and please let me know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Please show your code in this method `PrintToPrinter()`

Comment: This PrintToPrinter method is a system defined method,it has not been written by me.

Answer (score 0):

if you set first `startPageN` and `endPageN` equal to 0 then it will print all pages mean's now it will print twice one for `startPageN` and `endPageN` and 1 for indicated in number of copies. try this code hope it will help.

```
PetroDLL.Reports.rptBrokerageBillReportSeller2 rpt =
     new PetroDLL.Reports.rptBrokerageBillReportSeller2();
rpt.PrintToPrinter(0, false, 0, 0);
```